# Roblox not changing color of point light when changed with other instances

Tags: lua, roblox

I have this script:

```lua
local door = workspace.office.door
local signal = door.signal
local bcolor = script.Parent.Parent.Background

function fixdoor()
    if script:GetAttribute("fixing") then
        return
    end
    script:SetAttribute("fixing", true)
    if not door:GetAttribute("canbreak") then
        script.Parent.Parent.Background.Color3 = Color3.new(1, 0, 0)
        wait(.5)
        script.Parent.Parent.Background.Color3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
        script:SetAttribute("fixing", false)
        return
    end
    door:SetAttribute("canbreak", false)
    print(signal.PointLight.Color)
    bcolor.Color3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 0)
    signal.Color = Color3.new(1, 1, 0)
    signal.PointLight.Color = Color3.new(1, 1, 0)
    bcolor.Color3, signal.Color, signal.PointLight.Color = Color3.new(1, 1, 0) --Error here
    wait(.5)
    bcolor.Color3, signal.Color, signal.PointLight.Color = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
    wait(.5)
    bcolor.Color3, signal.Color, signal.PointLight.Color = Color3.new(1, 1, 0)
    wait(.5)
    bcolor.Color3, signal.Color, signal.PointLight.Color = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
    wait(.5)
    bcolor.Color3, signal.Color, signal.PointLight.Color = Color3.new(0, 1, 0)
    door:SetAttribute("broken", false)
    delay(20, function() door:SetAttribute("canbreak", true) end)
    wait(.5)
    bcolor.Color3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
    script:SetAttribute("fixing", false)
end

script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(fixdoor)
```

However, for some stupid reason, It gives me an error on line 22, even though It does the exact same as the other 3 lines saying: `Unable to assign property Color. Color3 expected, got nil`
This is very anoying, please help.

Comment: You cannot assign the same value to three properties in one statement. Break it up into multiple lines.